# Keeping two conch shells ( shankha) at home not allowed?

Tags: vishnu, belief, rituals, puja

I have heard people saying that the *shankh* - conch, which is used for blowing shouldn't be used for worshipping any deities via Abhishekam (especially God Vishnu) or, in any other way, and vice-versa.

Is there any scriptural truth to this?

If yes, then furthermore, I have heard one shouldn't keep two conch at home, since it create some kind of ritual deadlock or some *ashubh yoga*.

Now, if one can't keep two conch shells at home and also can't use the same conch for blowing and worshipping, then that itself creates a paradox.

What are the prescribed correct rules on these issues?

Comment: See the verses in this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20657/4732

Comment: @Rickross thanks!