# Two or more Idols of the same deity at home forbidden?

Tags: scripture, belief, vastu-shastra

Several elders say, that as per *vaastu-shastra* or some other treatises:

> it's forbidden to keep two idols of Lord Ganesha at home. Further,
> keeping three idols of *Bhagwati Durga* or any other *Deví* is also
> said to be forbidden. Also, one mustn't keep idols of *ugra*
> manifestations of God like *Maa Kali, Bhairava, Narasimha,* etc., at
> home. Some even say to not keep idols of *Suryadeva* too, at home.

Is this belief true?

Which scriptures say so?
And what all similar rules exists for other divinities?

Comment: See the verses quoted in my question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20657/4732

Comment: @Rickross, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this belief is true.

And this belief extends to all the five deities of the *Panchayatana-puja*, the *Pancha-Mahadevtas* viz. Ganesha, Surya, Vishnu, Shiva & Durga, besides *Shankha* (conches), and other *shilas*.

**The scriptural reference to this is found in the Narada Maha-Purana.**

> [Narada Purana
> 1.3.67](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n59/mode/2up)
>
> शंखचक्र**शिलालिंगविघ्नसूर्यद्वयं तथा** ॥ 
> **शक्तित्रयं न चैकत्र** पूजयेद्दुःखकारणम् ॥ ६७-१२० ॥
>
> > 120. **One should never worship two *shankhas*, two *chakras*, two *shilas* (the Shaligrama), or two *Shivalingas*, two idols of Vighneshvara (Ganesha), two of the Suns, and three Shaktis (Durga) together.** It is conducive to misery and sorrow.
>
> English Translation by Motilal Banarsidass Publishers