# What is the difference between chakra, yantra and mandala?

Tags: tantra, yantra

I have seen both the terms: Sri Chakra and Sri Yantra. Are these things different? In general, my question is whether Chakra and Yantra are the same or different. Also, what is the relation of Chakra and Yantra with Mandala?

Comment: I also have the same question. I've noticed terms like 'yantra' while going thru the sample pages of a few books on Tantra and Kashmiri Shaivism. As of yet, i haven't found the answer. Lets hope someone answers our queries.

Comment: Yantra can act as a substitute of an idol & a ghata. It can be drawn on ground by ointments like sandal & sindoor or engraved on metals like gold & copper. Like an idol, a yantra also undergoes the ritual of pranapratistha. Each deity has his/her unique yantra. A mandala is always drawn on ground & doesn't requires pranapratistha & isn't specialised for a particular deity. It is drawn for consecrating the ghata or fire within the kunda by natural pigments & hand. Mandalas like Sarvatobhadramandala can't substitute an idol by themselves. Sources : Brihat Tantrasara & Sharadatilaka Tantra

Comment: Shri Chakra is a ritual. All worships require a yantra. It can be a idol, or it can be "Likhit" (written or drawn) I.e. a mandala. The thing is all mandalas cannot be said to be yantras. One has to properly establish a yantra, which is not the case with mandalas. (Yantra is on which, he worships) see: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44397/21353

Comment: One more point: sometimes Shri yantra is also called shri- chakra. Generally yantras are movable, mandalas are not. For e.g. the mandala inscribed on copper plate becomes a yantra (like the Shri yantra) which can be three dimensional, while there are mandalas drawn specifically for rituals, for Asanas etc. (As if temporary)