# Why is worshipping multiple idols/symbols of certain deities forbidden in the Narada Purana?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, worship, ganesha, shakti

The Narada Purana (I.67.120) says-

> शंखचक्रशिलालिंगविघ्नसूर्यद्वयं तथा ।। ६७-१२० ।।
>
> शक्तित्रयं न चैकत्र पूजयेद्दुःखकारणम् ।।
>
> One must not perform simultaneous worship of Two Sankha Chakras or
> (Salagrama)Silas, two Shivalingas, two idols of Vighneshvara(Ganesa),Surya or Three
> idols of Shakti together. It is conducive to misery

Is there any reason behind such a prohibition?

And what is the significance behind the prohibition of simultaeous worship of three idols of Shakti as opposed to two of the other?

Comment: There is a similar question asked before https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20657/24460, which you can check